# How to calculate a running total?

Tags: php, mysql

I have looked at the other (many closed) running total questions in PHP however none satisfy

This is my query

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT SUM(game_total) AS totalgames, 
                 SUM(goals) AS totalgoals, 
                 FROM player 
                 WHERE year between 2006 and 2013 
                 AND month between 1 and 12 
                 GROUP BY 
                 year,
                 month between 1 and 3,
                 month between 4 and 6,
                 month between 7 and 9,
                 month between 10 and 12
                 ORDER BY year ASC, month ASC";
$rquery = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$show2 = '';

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rquery)){

                $games = $row['totalgames'];
                $goals = $row['totalgoals'];

                $gpg = $games == 0 ? 0 : number_format($goals/$games,2);
}
    ?>
```

If I echo the results of the query completing the loop I get the following result

```
+---------+----------+-----------+
|  Goals  |   Games  |   GPG     |
+---------+----------+-----------+
|  8      |   15     |   0.53    |
+---------+----------+-----------+
|  2      |   12     |   0.17    |
+---------+----------+-----------+
|  2      |   12     |   0.17    |
+---------+----------+-----------+
|  13     |   21     |   0.62    |
+---------+----------+-----------+
```

etc etc

However, I want to calculate a running GPG in the following manner

```
Goals/Games=GPG
8/15=0.53
10/27=0.37 (8+2/15+12)=GPG
12/39=0.31 (10+2/27+12)=GPG
25/60=0.41 (12+13/39+21)=GPG
```

and I want to echo it like this

0.53,0.37,0.31,0.41 etc etc

how would I do this?

Comment: Is there something in your coder that doesn't work?

Comment: In your question your pretty show that you get the results you want so I am unsure what your question is? Is there something in this code that isn't working?

Comment: I want to use those results to calculate the running GPG, as is described in the last part of the question

Comment: Ahhh, I understand now.  One second...

Comment: That was what we needed to know

Answer (score 0):

```
      $count = 0;
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rquery)){

            $count++; 

            $games = (int)$row['totalgames'];
            $goals = (int)$row['totalgoals'];

            $totalGames = 0;
            $totalGoals = 0;

            $totalGames += $goalData['games'];
            $totalGoals += $goalData['goals'];

            echo $totalGoals/$totalGames;
            echo ($count === mysql_num_rows($rquery)-1) '' : ',';

}
```

There we go, running total GPG as it iterates, commas separated without making an extra array.  That what you're looking for?

Comment: It is only returning one value

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I was speeding through.  Give me a sec.

Comment: perfect except its goals/games, however I am getting an error (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '''' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in)from - '' : ',';, - I've took it out and inspected the results and they are right - but I need the , I will probably figure it out however if you can help

Comment: My original solution gave better utility, but this one is simpler so it's the one I decided to recommend.  The $count thing is only needed here if you want the comma separated list without making any special arrays.

Comment: Can you try testing this code separate from the rest?  I have a feeling the problem is somewhere else, because I don't see anything here that should cause that error.

Comment: I tried the new code, same error

What do you mean "the rest" (sorry its 3am) you mean the query, its still the same error.

Comment: The new code without the ( '' : ',';) does not work at all " Illegal string offset", " Uninitialized string offset" errors ...

Comment: the original code you put up works, I only replaced ('' : ',';) with (, ',';) at the end. So I don't know what you want to do about your current answer as its returning too many errors.

Comment: Haha you have some funky stuff going on, based on what you're saying.  I'll come through, edit it, and comment here tomorrow when I get the chance if you wouldn't mind accepting it at that time. :)

Comment: well, the original one is working? Was there anything wrong with that one? I am also having trouble with GPG when games and goals are zero, it just misses it out.